# Fire event only when google map has been idle for number of seconds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing a google maps v3 javascript application that fetches new markers when the bounds of the map change. For that I'm using the "bounds_changed" listener.
Problem is that I want to restrict the calls I make and don't want to fire them every time the user changes the map viewport. How can I fire this call only if the map has been changed AND has been idle for, say, 1 second?

Thank you!
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare a global variable for timeout

```
var changetm = null;
```

then in the event you call

```
function event_handle(e){

    clearTimeout(changetm);
    changetm = setTimeout("fetch_new_markers()", 1000);

}
```

what that does is clear previous call (if exists) and then add the next call to the queue, wait for 1000 milisecon (1 sec) and call it. If in 1sec some event fired, it will clear the wait queue again...

tadah

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way tog et what you want is probably to use [setTimeout() and clearTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to prevent your 'update' call from triggering until the map has been idle for the desired length of time.

You could implement your `bounds_changed` listener so that it does something like:

```
function loadMarkersForCurrentMapBounds() {
    //code to load markers from your server goes here
}

function boundsChanged() {
    //...

    if (window.scheduledUpdate) {
        clearTimeout(window.scheduledUpdate);
    }
    window.scheduledUpdate = setTimeout(loadMarkersForCurrentMapBounds, 1000);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Binding some variable into window is good inn this case but not always good. What if some device does not have window object?

Comment: If there's no `window` object then it's virtually guaranteed that Google Maps isn't going to be working, either.  In practice the 'global' variable in your example would be bound to the `window` object too, the only real difference is that the code in my example makes it explicit, so that it's clear what context the global variable actually gets bound to.